# Unable to apt-get update on Kali Linux

Tags: apt, kali-linux

When I try to `apt-get update` it says:

> ```
> Get:1 http://archive-3.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.5 kB]
> Err:1 http://archive-3.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease
> The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
> Reading package lists... Done
> W: GPG error: http://archive-3.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG ED444FF07D8D0BF6 Kali Linux Repository <devel@kali.org>
> E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
> ```

My `/etc/apt/source.list` looks like this:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# For source package access, uncomment the following line
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 L$

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 2017.3 _Kali-rolling_ - Official Snapshot amd64 LI$
```

What should I do ? thanks!

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm not defending the quality of this question, but I think if there's an *actual* answer, we should try to use it. ["Note that I do not propose systematically closing Kali questions! Each question should be judged on its merit."](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/what-should-we-do-about-kali-linux-questions)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, your keys are outdated; you need to first update your keys. Try: `wget -q -O - archive.kali.org/archive-key.asc | apt-key add` and you’re  good to go.

Check out their [Tweet](https://twitter.com/kalilinux/status/959515084157538304?ref_src=twcamp%5Eshare%7Ctwsrc%5Em5%7Ctwgr%5Eemail%7Ctwcon%5E7046%7Ctwterm%5E2)